# How to combine html, javascript and css files into one .Vue component, grid component with external data

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-component

I saw this example on Vue.js website. This is an example of creating a reusable grid component and using it with external data.(If you want to see how it functions, here is the link :  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/grid-component.html?)  I have a basic understanding of how single file component works. I know `<template> <script> <style>` are accordingly for `html, javascript and css` parts. But I don't know how to make this grid component with external data fit in the skeleton. I didn't find any online tutorials about this. Please show how to fit this three files into one .vue file. Thank you.

HTML:

```
 <!-- component template -->
    <script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th v-for="key in columns"
              @click="sortBy(key)"
              :class="{ active: sortKey == key }">
              {{ key | capitalize }}
              <span class="arrow" :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'">
              </span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="entry in filteredHeroes">
            <td v-for="key in columns">
              {{entry[key]}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </script>
    
    <!-- demo root element -->
    <div id="demo">
      <form id="search">
        Search <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
      </form>
      <demo-grid
        :heroes="gridData"
        :columns="gridColumns"
        :filter-key="searchQuery">
      </demo-grid>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// register the grid component
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
    heroes: Array,
    columns: Array,
    filterKey: String
  },
  data: function () {
    var sortOrders = {}
    this.columns.forEach(function (key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredHeroes: function () {
      var sortKey = this.sortKey
      var filterKey = this.filterKey && this.filterKey.toLowerCase()
      var order = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1
      var heroes = this.heroes
      if (filterKey) {
        heroes = heroes.filter(function (row) {
          return Object.keys(row).some(function (key) {
            return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
          })
        })
      }
      if (sortKey) {
        heroes = heroes.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
          a = a[sortKey]
          b = b[sortKey]
          return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * order
        })
      }
      return heroes
    }
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize: function (str) {
      return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function (key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    }
  }
})

// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['name', 'power'],
    gridData: [
      { name: 'Chuck Norris', power: Infinity },
      { name: 'Bruce Lee', power: 9000 },
      { name: 'Jackie Chan', power: 7000 },
      { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 }
    ]
  }
})
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid #42b983;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

th {
  background-color: #42b983;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.66);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

th, td {
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

th.active {
  color: #fff;
}

th.active .arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.66;
}

.arrow.asc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}

.arrow.dsc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}
```

My .vue file right now:

```
<template>
 <!-- component template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="key in columns"
          @click="sortBy(key)"
          :class="{ active: sortKey == key }">
          {{ key | capitalize }}
          <span class="arrow" :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'">
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="entry in filteredHeroes">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<!-- demo root element -->
<div id="demo">
  <form id="search">
    Search <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
  </form>
  <demo-grid
    :heroes="gridData"
    :columns="gridColumns"
    :filter-key="searchQuery">
  </demo-grid>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    var sortOrders = {}
    this.columns.forEach(function (key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredHeroes: function () {
      var sortKey = this.sortKey
      var filterKey = this.filterKey && this.filterKey.toLowerCase()
      var order = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1
      var heroes = this.heroes
      if (filterKey) {
        heroes = heroes.filter(function (row) {
          return Object.keys(row).some(function (key) {
            return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
          })
        })
      }
      if (sortKey) {
        heroes = heroes.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
          a = a[sortKey]
          b = b[sortKey]
          return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * order
        })
      }
      return heroes
    }
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize: function (str) {
      return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function (key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    }
  }
}
</script>


<style scoped>
    body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid #42b983;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

th {
  background-color: #42b983;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.66);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

th, td {
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

th.active {
  color: #fff;
}

th.active .arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.66;
}

.arrow.asc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}

.arrow.dsc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}
</style>
```

I don't know what to do with the javascript file in `<script>`, obviously I can't just copy it and paste. But I am confused about what changes I should make.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but are you sure you understood the basics of a SFC? If so, you would know you already have the results there. You just need to put them into the right place. However, you didn't even try solving your problem on your own, according to Stack Overflow rules.

Comment: @Aer0 I tried, but I think I didn't put them in the right place, because there are many errors showing up in the inspector. I can only have the search bar working somehow. Do you know what should I do with the html part?  I am very confused. I only know about very simple examples on SFC.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're actually not sticking to our rules. If you would have read the guide properly you should be able to easily create an SFC. See the first image here. It's clearly written 'black on white' https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: @Aer0 Thank you for your reminding! I have added my failed vue file at the end of my question. I have read the website before ,but maybe I didn't get it fully since I am new to this.  I don't know what to do with multiple parts in each file. Can you please read through my mistaken code and give me some hints?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've set up your build pipeline properly your SFC doesn't look correct. Taking a deeper look into the [guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) about SFC you have to wrap each part of your code into its own block, meaning.

- HTML (template)
- JavaSCript (script)
- CSS (style)

Your SFC would then have to look like this.

```
<template>
  <!-- HTML markup here -->
</template>

<script>
  // JavaScript code here
</script>

<style>
  /* CSS stylings here */
</style>
```

In your very example, you're mixing the `template` and `script` block which is not supposed to look like that.

Comment: So, the `<script> ` part of the HTML file, as the component template, should not be in <template> but in <script> in SFC?